# Create a file with the same name as a directory in Python

Tags: python, macos, io, filesystems

I have a directory `/project/my_name/`

I need to create a file `/project/my_name`

But :

```
with open(filename, 'w') as outfile:
    outfile.write(my_content)
```

Raise `IOError: [Errno 21] Is a directory: u'/project/my_name'`

Any help?

Comment: Change the filename to `/project/my_name.txt`. There cant be a file with the same name as directory at the same location.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From the filesystem's point of view, a directory is a kind of file. You can't have two files with the same name.

Comment: I was hoping for a miracle ... Thank you for the back to basics ;-)